# I need to find the max value across a set number of columns, and divide each individual record by that value. Any help on how? Using Aggregate?

Tags: r

Using R
I have a dataframe with many columns and millions of rows.   For a specific set of columns, I need to find the maximum value across that set of columns and divide each record by that maximum value less 0.00001 as the results must be between 0-1.

In the example below the first table is an example of the data where it would be found that the Max is 96.   Then each value is divided by 96+0.0001 and added as new variables.

Any help would be awesome!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this as input:

```
df <- data.frame(PIN = c('a','b','c','d'),
                 v1 = c(79,6,96,56),
                 v2 = c(77,22,2,16),
                 v3 = c(57,96,10,80))

  PIN v1 v2 v3
1   a 79 77 57
2   b  6 22 96
3   c 96  2 10
4   d 56 16 80
```

Then using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-1), ~.x / max(df[,2:4]) - 0.00001)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-1), round, digits = 5))
```

Output:

```
  PIN      v1      v2      v3
1   a 0.82291 0.80207 0.59374
2   b 0.06249 0.22916 0.99999
3   c 0.99999 0.02082 0.10416
4   d 0.58332 0.16666 0.83332
```

The maximum is found over the columns `2` to `4` (`max(df[,2:4])`). You can replace the index with the ones you want to check for the maximum

Edit: When you have 0:

```
df <- data.frame(PIN = c('a','b','c','d'),
                 v1 = c(79,6,96,56),
                 v2 = c(77,22,2,16),
                 v3 = c(57,96,10,0))

  PIN v1 v2 v3
1   a 79 77 57
2   b  6 22 96
3   c 96  2 10
4   d 56 16  0

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-1), ~.x / max(df[,2:4]) - 0.00001)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-1), round, digits = 5)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(-1), ~ifelse(.x<0,0,.x)))


  PIN      v1      v2      v3
1   a 0.82291 0.80207 0.59374
2   b 0.06249 0.22916 0.99999
3   c 0.99999 0.02082 0.10416
4   d 0.58332 0.16666 0.00000
```

Comment: This works amazingly!!!   Thanks!!!    One additional side effect I have now though is where there were values of zero, the result is now -0.0001.   Every record must fall between 0 and 1, inclusive of 0.    How would I fix this?

Comment: You can add `mutate(across(c(-1), ~ifelse(.x<0,0,.x)))` within the code (as a next instruction). This will replace negative values (such as `-0,0001` by 0 it self). See edit @DataScienceDave

Comment: This means you have memory issues. Consider using `data.table` then or buying RAM/using a cluster to process your data

Comment: When I say use `data.table`, do `your_data <- data.table::data.table(your_data)`, and your problem should be resolved @DataScienceDave

Comment: Sorry for my quick response.  I increased my memory allocation but then found I had an error in my code and fixed it and it worked.